# Is it true to say that only root/sudo can change file permissions for u,g,o of a file?

Tags: permissions

I always worked with Linux alone (via a root/`sudo` user account), never in a team, which makes me ask this:

Is it true to say that only root/`sudo` can change file permissions for u,g,o of a file?
I mean, if we create a non-root user account (which doesn't have `sudo` access), this user account could **never** change u,g,o file permissions, right?

Comment: No, it's not true. The owner if the file can change the permissions. (Try it.) I'd give you a reference if I'd find anything better than the [chmod(2) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html)

Comment: Discretionary access control (DAC) is the default file access control, so the owner can give permissions to others. Mandatory access control (MAC) can also be used with some Linux Security Module like SELinux.

Answer (score 3):

A non-root account can only change the permissions of the files they own, never other people files permissions

Let's imagine a test with `a` and `b`, both regular accounts :

We have a directory :

```bash
-rw-r--r-- 1 a    a     0 Jan  1 10:20 a_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 b    b     0 Jan  1 10:20 b_file
```

```bash
 # sudo -u a chmod 640 b_file
chmod: changing permissions of 'b_file': Operation not permitted
```

```bash
 # sudo -u a chmod 750 a_file ; ls -l
-rwxr-x--- 1 a    a     0 Jan  1 10:20 a_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 b    b     0 Jan  1 10:20 b_file
```

You can see that `a` can only modify permissions on their own files